# Right scope context for processing in pubsub consumers

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, google-cloud-pubsub, coroutine

We use a Kotlin backend and Google PubSub.
When we receive message, we need to process the payload and update our DB accordingly.
This processing might take a while (up to minute).

At first I used `runBlocking` to do this, but as this, along with `GlobalScope` seem to be highly discouraged, I'd like to understand all the options and the implications.

1. `runBlocking` - will this make the server stuck when more message get piled up/higher scale?
2. GlobalScope
3. CoroutineScope / withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
4. something else I missed.

The pubsub consumer code looks as follows:

```
override fun receiveMessage(message: PubsubMessage, consumer: AckReplyConsumer) {

     val id = message.messageId
     val data = message.data.toStringUtf8()

     val payload: PostProcessingPayload?
     try {
         payload = Json.decodeFromString<PostProcessingPayload>(data)
         val userId = payload.userId

         runBlocking { // --> will this adversely affect the server?

             val isResourceCreated = someService.processPayload(userId)
             if (!isResourceCreated) {
                 println("failed to process and create resource")
             }

         }

     } catch (e: SerializationException) {
         println("failed to parse payload")
     } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
         println("failed to parse payload")
     } catch (e: Exception) {
         println("payload processing service threw exception")
     } finally {
         consumer.ack()
     }

 }
```

Comment: How is `processPayload` defined?

Comment: `interface Service { suspend fun generateTrip(userId: Int): Boolean
}`

Comment: Well, the way you're doing it right now is synchronous. You wait until `processPayload` (`generateTrip`) completes before you return from `receiveMessage`. To process each received message asynchronously, you might want to add it to a queue and process it from another thread. Maybe look at Channels.

Comment: But when the consumer function is triggered/called by pubsub, isn't it already another thread?  Or all thoae consumer are running all in the same thread?

Comment: I don't know how PubSub works, but I think it typically uses threads, though not one thread per call, but most probably a thread pool with a limited number of threads in order to avoid running out of memory. I've added the relevant tag to your question so that people who know PubSub may see it and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're currently handling it will probably not work out for PubSub, and will certainly not leverage your suspendable backend infrastructure. The main point of coroutines is their ability to execute IO operations without blocking threads, but in your example you're blocking the PubSub handler thread for the entire duration of the job.

If you replace `runBlocking` with `GlobalScope.launch`, you'll have jobs hanging out there with no ability to control their number or limit their execution time. That eventually ends up in app crashes due to resource exhaustion.

You should most likely not consider using `launch(Dispatchers.IO)`. You'd need that in the opposite scenario: when you're already inside a coroutine, but need to execute blocking code.

In order to proceed, I think you have to get more info on how your Kotlin backend works. Here are examples of the things to find out:

1. Does it expose a `CoroutineScope` you can attach your job to?
2. Does it have a specific `Dispatcher`?
3. How does it handle the concern of backpressure?
4. How does job control work? Is there a mechanism to cancel all pending jobs?

Based on this knowledge you'll be able to replace your `runBlocking` with some other call, similar to `myBackendScope.launch`.

Comment: Ok, so the first part of the flow -  the consumer callback provided by Google PubSub, `interface MessageReceiver { void receiveMessage(final PubsubMessage message, final AckReplyConsumer consumer); } `, is java-ish, so it is not invoked under a specific Dispatcher scope.  Then, I call the `processPayload` function which is a suspending function. This function includes:  1. parallel `async` tasks, which is why I added `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to the processPayload function. But maybe that's wrong too (?)
2. http requests
3. DB (postgres) queries/updates
4. AI-modules calls

Comment: The main question is, how do you "enter the coroutine world" that's appropriate for the framework your project is using. Regarding parallel async tasks, the thing to know is whether any of the IO types you mention are made through non-suspendable, blocking functions. If so, then you do need Dispatchers.IO. You mentioned that your `interface Service` declares a `suspend fun`. If it's properly implemented, it doesn't do blocking calls, but there's no guarantee it's properly implemented.

Comment: our DB queries are run in IO context, this is the signature `suspend fun <T> dbQuery(block: () -> T): T = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { block() }`, and for http we use Ktor, I'm not sure about their internals.
Now, if all are implemented properly, would you propose to block the message processing before ACK (acknowledging) the pubsub message?, and if so - how? because it seems you discouraged the use of runBlocking and any forms of `launch`. Maybe I just misunderstood something.

Comment: also, the pubsub receiver are received in new threads, Google PubSub are using ExecutorProvider of 5 threads by deafult per Subscriber. That means that by default our single subscriber can only handle 5 messages at a time. Instead of manually setting an ExecutorProvider with thousands of threads, is it possible to mitigate the thread spawning by making the subscribers be trigerred or process message in coroutine dispatcher / coroutines.

Comment: It would be great if PubSub allowed returning without ACK, and then using some kind of callback mechanism to let it know asynchronously. That would then be easy to integrate into suspendable operation.

Comment: I tried that, instead of runBlocking I used `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch` and inside of it, after processing the task, I called `ack`. It seems to work. 
Is this the optimized way ? How can we make sure that we don't reach resource exhaustion? Or is it handle by the dispatcher pool behind the scenes? (i.e - queued what cannot be handled by the threadpool at a given moment) ?

Comment: Yes, the IO thread pool has an upper bound. BTW no need for `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`, since you noticed that your suspendable functions already use `withContext(IO)`. Instead you can write `GlobalScope.launch`  -- and yes, this will have all the risks that make `GlobalScope` advised against.

Comment: Great, so to make sure I understood correctly everything - aside from CoroutineScope(IO).launch and GlobalScope, what if we use `CoroutineScope(Job()).launch`, it will simply use the current thread's context, and the suspendable functions already use withContent(IO), so all those options are essentially the same? Or there are nuances that we should be aware of ? (or maybe even better options?)

Comment: `CoroutineScope(Job())` doesn't do anything more than `GlobalScope`, so you should prefer the simpler one. By default, the `Default` dispatcher is used, and in a properly implemented app it's a good choice. Every `suspend fun` that intends to make blocking calls is required to make them inside `withContext(IO)`.